# Why would a company change it's landing page based on a user's operating system?

Tags: website-design, usability, user-behavior, user-research, users

I was on www.Zillow.com today and I noticed that the landing page differs on both Windows XP and Windows 8 versus my Macbook Air running OS X 10.9; all running the latest version of firefox. Why would a company change it's landing page based on a user's operating system? Are they creating a unique experience based off profiles of an operating system's user?

*note: The site both loads under the same domain, www.zillow.com. On both versions of Windows (XP & 10) the new version of the landing page is loaded. On Mac OS X, the old version of the landing page is loaded.

Comment: Hate to say it, but: it's not an old version stuck in the browser cache is it?

Comment: You are correct @vincebowdren, deleted willow out of my laval storage and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a browser caching issue not a User Experience problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Companies are always looking for ways to better target customers, and there are documented cases of using operating system information to do this.  For example, [Orbitz suggested higher price hotels to Mac users](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702304458604577488822667325882):

> Orbitz Worldwide Inc. has found that people who use Apple Inc.'s Mac computers spend as much as 30% more a night on hotels, so the online travel agency is starting to show them different, and sometimes costlier, travel options than Windows visitors see.

It is possible that Zillow is doing the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately my zillow.com mishap was due to a caching issue but it's still good to know that other sites use this for marketing. Thanks!